# Remove comma from string literal

Tags: javascript

I want to concatenate string with array Item.

I tried following.

```js
const str = "I have following things:"
const arr = ["chair", "table", "bed"];


const tootlTipText = `${str}
${arr.map(item => `- ${item} \n`)}`;
                

console.log(tootlTipText);
```

It display , in between. I tried to find and can't find what is the issue.

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use `map`. Use `reduce`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that by default, when you convert an array to a string, it's done as though you called `.join(",")`. To avoid that, call `join` yourself with whatever separator you want, perhaps `""`:

```js
const str = "I have following things:"
const arr = ["chair", "table", "bed"];


const tootlTipText = `${str}
${arr.map(item => `- ${item} \n`).join("")}`;
                

console.log(tootlTipText);
```

Alternatively, you could use a simple loop with string concatenation:

```js
const str = "I have following things:"
const arr = ["chair", "table", "bed"];

let tootlTipText = `${str}\n`;
for (const item of arr) {
    tootlTipText += `- ${item} \n`;
}

console.log(tootlTipText);
```

Some folks would also use `reduce` for this; personally I don't like `reduce` except in functional programming with predefined, tested reducers, but:

```js
const str = "I have following things:"
const arr = ["chair", "table", "bed"];

const tootlTipText = arr.reduce(
    (str, item) => str + `- ${item} \n`,
    `${str}\n`
);

console.log(tootlTipText);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.map()` returns an array. It should be converted to string.

```
const tootlTipText = `${str}
    ${arr.map(item => `- ${item} \n`).join('')}`;
```